# error page is set to default in laravel. how to disable

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an existing project where errors are not getting displayed and redirecting to default error page. Help me to view errors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you are trying to say? 

And, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, so that we could give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Handle Debugging in Laravel is very easy. You just need to change the value of `debug` in `app/config/app.php` directory.

By default it should be `'debug' => evn(APP_DEBUG,false),` (accepts boolean)

It means env() function will find the variable `APP_DEBUG` from `.env` and use that value, in case `APP_DEBUG` not found in `.env` the default value is false.

Now, In `.env` file Set `APP_DEBUG=true` to show the error message and set `APP_DEBUG=false` or remove this variable for hiding them.

Comment: Thanks. But this helped me:  //return response()->view('errors.something_went_wrong', [], 500);
    return parent::render($request, $exception);          I have commented view page

Comment: Do you want to change the page view/style for 500 responses?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Sure @NicoHaase, Thanks for find the mistake.